# Only approved users should post blogs in django

Tags: python, django, model, django-users

I have build a blog based web-application using Django , Where users can login and wrote articles and those articles are being posted after admin approval. But right now all users can post articles. I want only those users to post the articles which are approved . I am using default Django user model . From users I only create a profile model.
My users models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pic')
    posting_post  = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self , *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
```

**My postcreate view is:**

```
class PostCreateView(TagMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image',]


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('admin-approval')
```

**and my html for create post is:**

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create'%}">New Post</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, add a BooleanField `can_post` and then when the user log in, handle it the same way you are handling `profile_image`,  then check it in the it condition in template.

Comment: I add a boolean field posting_post is profile model . The user model is a django default model . And i do not know how can i handle this in user model and then in views

Comment: You have to get it, I don't know if this will work, `request. user.profile.posting_post', but this will surely work `Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id` and either add it to the session and pass it in context.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean field in the blog post model named approved or not and set default False, and in your views user query to exlude objects where approved=False.

Comment: Sir this will put the check on thepost , not on user . My question is for user model

Comment: oh you can use this on user too. Like Allowed_to_post .